# Enabling DTD support in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have various xml documents that I need to store in a database column. The documents contain references to a DTD and SQL Server won't import the xml because it is a security risk.
How can I enable DTD support on the database so it will let me insert the xml content.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `CONVERT` it first.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184(v=sql.110).aspx#code-snippet-8):

> you can import XML data from a data file that contains a DTD by using
>   the OPENROWSET(BULK...) function and then specifying the CONVERT
>   option in the SELECT clause of the command. The basic syntax for the
>   command is:
>
> > `INSERT ... SELECT CONVERT(…) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK...)`

Example:

```
INSERT T1
  SELECT CONVERT(xml, BulkColumn, 2) FROM 
    OPENROWSET(Bulk 'c:\temp\Dtdfile.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) [rowsetresults];
```

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this code before and I will use it for the time being. For the sake of completeness, I'm still looking for the answer to how to enable database-wide DTD support without having to use the CONVERT command.