# Dynamic Table Creation based on Document Type Definition of XML

Tags: c#, sql, xml, t-sql, powershell

Good Morning Techie,

May any one share your expertise .

i have an XML document (1GB Size) with a Document Type Definition.

i need to load the data to sql table, but the challenge is the table structure must be created during run time depends upon the .dtd file.

The .dtd file is keep on changing based on customer to customer

i am new to the xml, Please help me. i can provide xml and .dtd if its required.

**code i have used to pull data from xml to table**

```
;With Cte

 AS

 (SELECT i.value('(../@action)[1]','varchar(20)') AppAction,

        i.value('(../@id)[1]','varchar(20)') AppId,

      i.value('.','varchar(20)') Notes,

     i.value('(../BaseVehicle/@id)[1]','varchar(20)') BaseVehicle,

      k.value('(./Qual/@id)[1]','varchar(20)') Qual,

     i.value('(../Qty)[1]','varchar(20)') Qty,

    i.value('(../PartType/@id)[1]','varchar(20)') PartType,

   i.value('(../SubModel/@id)[1]','varchar(20)') SubModel,
    i.value('(../EngineBase/@id)[1]','varchar(20)') EngineBase,
    i.value('(../EngineVIN/@id)[1]','varchar(20)') EngineVIN,
    k.value('(./MfrLabel)[1]','varchar(20)') MfrLabel,
    i.value('(../Position/@id)[1]','varchar(20)') PositionId,
    i.value('(../Part)[1]','varchar(20)') Part,
    k.value('(./Qual/param/@value)[1]','varchar(20)') ParamValue,
    j.value('.','varchar(20)') RecordCount

FROM @X.nodes('AMUL/App[@action="A"]/Note') x(i)

OUTER APPLY x.i.nodes('../../Footer/RecordCount')y(j) 

OUTER APPLY y.j.nodes('../../App')z(k))

 SELECT 


AppAction,AppId,BaseVehicle,Qual,Qty,PartType,MfrLabel,PositionId,Part,ParamValue,SubModel,EngineBase,EngineVIN,RecordCount,

       STUFF((SELECT ' ; ' + Notes 

            FROM   Cte X WHERE X.BaseVehicle = Y.BaseVehicle 

           GROUP  BY BaseVehicle,Notes

          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') Note                 

FROM   Cte Y 

 GROUP  BY 
BaseVehicle,AppAction,AppId,Qual,Qty,PartType,MfrLabel,PositionId,Part,ParamValue,SubModel,EngineBase,EngineVIN,RecordCount
```

Thanks a ton.

Comment: any additional details you provide will be helpful, but off the top of my head, if I had to do this task, I would not want to do it strictly in SQL, but develop an external tool to do it in .NET or some other language you are familiar with.

Comment: appreciate your help. please suggest. i got stuck here. :) can we attached here .dtd or xml file here.

Comment: what programming experience do you have?

Comment: sql, but i can give a try using c#.net

Comment: any luck techie...... please

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. Show us what you have tried so far (your code) and explain what particular problem you need help with. As it stands your question is far too broad and doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: please provide some sample data, especially the DTD and a relevant snippet of your XML.

Comment: Did you have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25457145/5089204?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: i have added the code i used to pull data from xml. but the challenge i am facing each time .dtd of xml is getting changed. i am trying to automate the process, so whenever file dropped in a path it push data to table, and schema of the table based on .dtd file.

Comment: @Shnugo: thanks Shnugo. but unfortunately it is not what i am looking.

Comment: I don't know of any automatic way to transfer an XML with a DTD into kind of table(s) structure. Analysing/parsing DTD is not trivial for sure... I've never done it though (thank god!)... It might be easier to extract the target table's structure from the XML itself...  At least if your XML does not include any nested structures.

Comment: @Shnugo: my xml is of nested structure :), and i am now clueless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97937/discussion-between-shan-and-shnugo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a first attempt:

It will create (actually just declare) four tables (file, app, qual and note)
Your data is inserted with created foreign keys.
The last lines are a fully joined resultset
I included all XML-Nodes into the target tables to make sure, that missed information is not lost...

Just copy the whole thing into an empty query window, execute and explorer the final result whether this fits to your needs or not.

If yes, please don't forget to vote up and accept. This took quite some effort :-)

Happy coding!

```
DECLARE @x xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ACES version="3.0"> 
<Header> 
<Company>Godrej</Company> 
<SenderName>chail</SenderName> 
<SenderPhone>xxx-712-xxxx</SenderPhone> 
<TransferDate>2009-09-30</TransferDate> 
<BrandAAIAID>tbzx</BrandAAIAID> 
<DocumentTitle>Godrej Data</DocumentTitle> 
<EffectiveDate>2009-09-30</EffectiveDate> 
<SubmissionType>FULL</SubmissionType> 
<xcdbVersionDate>2008-08-28</xcdbVersionDate> 
<reltersionDate>2008-06-10</reltersionDate> 
<xcbdVersionDate>2020-09-25</xcbdVersionDate> 
</Header> 

<App action="A" id="1"> 
<BaseVehicle id="2555"/> 
<Qual id="15231"> 
<text>Light Duty Brakes</text> 
</Qual> 
<Qty>2</Qty> 
<PartType id="10054"/> 
<MfrLabel>Professional Grade</MfrLabel> 
<Position id="22"/> 
<Part>816-4000</Part> 
</App> 
<App action="A" id="3"> 
<BaseVehicle id="2557"/> 
<Qual id="15231"> 
<text>Light Duty Brakes</text> 
</Qual> 
<Qty>2</Qty> 
<PartType id="10054"/> 
<MfrLabel>Professional Grade</MfrLabel> 
<Position id="22"/> 
<Part>816-4000</Part> 
</App> 
<App action="A" id="908"> 
<BaseVehicle id="1513"/> 
<Qual id="9174"> 
<text>Standard Nut</text> 
</Qual> 
<Qual id="21521"> 
<text>Requires Stamped Retainer And Cotter Pin</text> 
</Qual> 
<Qty>2</Qty> 
<PartType id="10054"/> 
<MfrLabel>Professional Grade</MfrLabel> 
<Position id="22"/> 
<Part>816-4018</Part> 
</App> 
<App action="A" id="4007"> 
<BaseVehicle id="7947"/> 
<Qual id="9743"> 
<param value="8/91"/> 
<text>Thru 8/91</text> 
</Qual> 
<Qty>2</Qty> 
<PartType id="10014"/> 
<MfrLabel>Professional Grade</MfrLabel> 
<Position id="22"/> 
<Part>816-4265</Part> 
</App> 
<App action="A" id="1"> 
<BaseVehicle id="5861" /> 
<Note>Manual</Note> 
<Qty>1</Qty> 
<PartType id="13117" /> 
<Position id="12" /> 
<Part>955-304</Part> 
</App> 

<App action="A" id="9951"> 
<BaseVehicle id="3883" /> 
<Note>Reflector</Note> 
<Note>Packaging Type: Box</Note> 
<Qty>1</Qty> 
<PartType id="11720" /> 
<Position id="88" /> 
<Part>1650140</Part> 
</App> 
<App action="A" id="16578"> 
<BaseVehicle id="18667" /> 
<SubModel id="694" /> 
<Note>Composite Type</Note> 
<Note>Smoked Lens, w/Black Trim</Note> 
<Qty>1</Qty> 
<PartType id="10762" /> 
<Position id="12" /> 
<Part>1591142</Part> 
</App> 
<App action="A" id="19633"> 
<BaseVehicle id="18659" /> 
<Note>Power</Note> 
<Note>w/Heat</Note> 
<Note>wo/Memory</Note> 
<Qty>1</Qty> 
<PartType id="13117" /> 
<Position id="12" /> 
<Part>955-1162</Part> 
</App> 
<App action="A" id="83948"> 
<BaseVehicle id="4470" /> 
<Note>Compare to Original</Note> 
<Note>Bulb Call-Out Size: 194</Note> 
<Note>Wattage: 1.2</Note> 
<Note>Light Color: White</Note> 
<Qty>1</Qty> 
<PartType id="11730" /> 
<Position id="1" /> 
<Part>194W-SMD</Part> 
</App> 
<App action="A" id="2"> 
<BaseVehicle id="4935" /> 
<Note>M14 x 1.50 Thread</Note> 
<Note>Package Quantity: 5</Note> 
<Note>Dorman - AutoGrade - Boxed</Note> 
<Note>Packaging Type: Box</Note> 
<Qty>1</Qty> 
<PartType id="5560" /> 
<Position id="1" /> 
<Part>090-053</Part> 
</App> 
<App action="A" id="288250"> 
<BaseVehicle id="16865" /> 
<SubModel id="20" /> 
<EngineBase id="5461" /> 
<EngineVIN id="40" /> 
<Note>Wheel Lock Type: Female Spline</Note> 
<Note>Package Quantity: 4</Note> 
<Note>Packaging Type: Card</Note> 
<Note>Thread Size: 1/2-20</Note> 
<Note>Chrome</Note> 
<Note>Overall Length (In): 1.425</Note> 
<Note>Steel</Note> 
<Note>Thread Handling: Right Hand Thread</Note> 
<Qty>1</Qty> 
<PartType id="16214" /> 
<Position id="1" /> 
<Part>711-221</Part> 
</App> 
<Footer> 
<RecordCount>1772522</RecordCount> 
</Footer> 
</ACES>';


DECLARE @tblFile TABLE(FileID INT
                  ,ACES_Version VARCHAR(10)
                  ,Header_Company VARCHAR(100)
                  ,Header_SenderName VARCHAR(100)
                  --further Header-fields here 
                  ,Footer_RecordCount INT
                  ,HeaderNode XML
                  ,FooterNode XML);

INSERT INTO @tblFile
SELECT 1 AS FileID --Add something senseful here
      ,@x.value('/ACES[1]/@version','varchar(max)') AS ACES_Version
      ,@x.value('(/ACES/Header/Company)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Header_Company
      ,@x.value('(/ACES/Header/SenderName)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Header_SenderName
      --further fields of header here
      ,@x.value('(/ACES/Footer/RecordCount)[1]','int') AS ACES_RecordCount
      ,@x.query('/ACES/Header') AS HeaderNode
      ,@x.query('/ACES/Footer') AS FooterNode;

DECLARE @tblApp TABLE(AppID INT
                     ,FileID INT
                     ,Action VARCHAR(10)
                     ,ID INT
                     ,BaseVehicleID INT
                     ,Qty INT
                     --further App-fields here
                     ,QualNodes XML
                     ,NoteNodes XML
                     ,AppNode XML);

INSERT INTO @tblApp
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY One.App.value('@id','int')) AS AppID
      ,1 AS FileID --Add something senseful here
      ,One.App.value('@action','varchar(10)') AS Action
      ,One.App.value('@id','int') AS ID
      ,One.App.value('BaseVehicle[1]/@id','int') AS BaseVehicleID
      ,One.App.value('Qty[1]','int') AS Qty
      --further App-fields here
      ,'<Quals>' + CAST(One.App.query('Qual') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '</Quals>' AS QualNodes
      ,'<Notes>' + CAST(One.App.query('Note') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '</Notes>' AS NoteNodes
      ,One.App.query('.') AS AppNode
FROM @x.nodes('/ACES/App') AS One(App);

DECLARE @tblQual TABLE(AppID INT
                      ,FileID INT
                      ,QualID INT
                      ,ID INT
                      ,Text VARCHAR(150)
                      ,ParamValue VARCHAR(150)
                      ,QualNode XML);

INSERT INTO @tblQual
SELECT AppID
      ,FileID
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AppID ORDER BY One.Qual.value('@id','int')) AS QualID
      ,One.Qual.value('@id','int') AS ID
      ,One.Qual.value('text[1]','varchar(max)') AS Text
      ,One.Qual.value('param[1]/@value','varchar(max)') AS ParamValue
      ,One.Qual.query('.') AS QualNode
FROM @tblApp AS tblApp
CROSS APPLY tblApp.QualNodes.nodes('/Quals/Qual') One(Qual)


DECLARE @tblNotes TABLE(AppID INT
                      ,FileID INT
                      ,NoteID INT
                      ,ID INT
                      ,NoteText VARCHAR(150)
                      ,NoteNode XML);

INSERT INTO @tblNotes
SELECT AppID
      ,FileID  
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AppID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NoteID
      ,One.Note.value('@id','int') AS ID
      ,One.Note.value('.','varchar(max)') AS NoteText
      ,One.Note.query('.') AS NoteNode
FROM @tblApp AS tblApp
CROSS APPLY tblApp.NoteNodes.nodes('/Notes/Note') One(Note)

SELECT * 
FROM @tblFile AS f
INNER JOIN @tblApp AS a ON f.FileID=a.FileID
LEFT JOIN @tblQual AS q ON q.AppID=a.AppID
LEFT JOIN @tblNotes AS n ON n.AppID=a.AppID
```

Comment: my hats off to you!!!! :) Thanks a lot....... Testing with the largest xml i have..... :)

Comment: @Shan, Thx, I like the difficult and love the impossible :-))